# What do all the "icons" mean in Wireshark 2.0?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I have recently started using Wireshark 2.0 and it seems the "icons" in the frame number column help me better understand the traffic. However, I'm not sure what some of them mean.

Looking at [chapter 6 of the manual](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChapterWork.html) didn't help much and most of the documentation has not been updated yet for 2.0.

Here are some icons I see:

[image: Icons in Wireshark]

So far, my guesses about them are:

- edges indicate stream start / end
- frames which have a full line belong to the stream
- frames which have a dotted line do not belong to the stream
- arrows indicate DNS requests and replies or Ping requests and replies
- checkmarks indicate the frame that was ACKed by the selected frame
- double checkmarks indicate double ACKs

I did not get the meaning of the dots.

Are my assumptions correct, what is the meaning of dots and where could I find more information about it?

Comment: You can probably figure it out by reading the text beside it and associating the icons with the things that they associate with, so you are only unable to figure out the dots? My guess is just that when two packets are connected either by a  solid or dotted line they mean almost the same thing. The dots must have some shade of meaning different.

Comment: Yes, the dots are most puzzling. They appear on fragmented packets, but also on certificates in TLS, request/response in HTTP. It seems to be about things which are more related to the selection than the rest of the stream. But switching between e.g. three dots, the dots may change, which is again mysterious.

Answer (score 3):

It is the related packets column.
Laura talks about it in the webinar [Introduction to Wireshark 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLfYuO6pdVA&feature=youtu.be). Jump to 20 minutes.
You can watch the video also at [wireshark University](http://www.wiresharktraining.com/)